# How do I get E-mail folders from a Gmail.com POP server using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, desktop-application, pop3

I have managed to:

1. Connect to Gmail.com POP server (pop.gmail.com) Port 995 using Socket methods (*TcpClient*) and POP3 Commands (*USER, PASS, STAT*)
2. Get successful response from Gmail.com POP server using POP3 (*STAT*) command to my VB.net application (*+OK*)
3. Retrieve E-mails list from my Gmail.com account
4. Read those E-mails in plain Text format using a Textbox control.

The problem is that i get all the E-mails from the whole account, means :
If the inbox folder has (90) E-mails, sent folder has (10) E-mails and trash folder has (10) E-mails, then i get (100) E-mails in my application and they are not categorized, means you can not tell which one of them from inbox and which one is from trash.

So, my question is:

- Is there a way to retrieve these Folders separately in my VB.net application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at least not with `POP3`.

The [`POP3`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html) protocoll does not offer things like *folders*. You should probably use the [`IMAP`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html) protocoll, then.